# Tomcat 6: JVM fatal error

Tags: tomcat, jvm, fatal-error

I have tocmat6 server and JSF webapp working on it. Till now it all worked just fine. But recently it started to falling down with error:

```
#
#  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (synchronizer.cpp:1401), pid=1584, tid=2817506160
#  guarantee(mid->header()->is_neutral()) failed: invariant
```

Comment: That is an internal error in the JVM. See if you can update to the latest version/patchlevel of the JVM.

Comment: Well I use sun's jdk 1.6_26... before that I used openJdk, so when I switched JVM nothing happend

Comment: nothing happened? same error with both JVM?

Comment: yep... same error. In dump JVM version is new

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on a specific server, an OpenVZ/ProxMox instance, that was running Ubuntu 11.04 natty narwal with a standard sun-java6 package 1.6.26. As Ubuntu is not providing any newer JVM, I upgraded manually with 1.6.31 from Oracle website and this fixed the issue.